# relational databases and auto incrementing

Tags: mysql, database

hello i'm trying to make two databases linked for a book review system i'm creating

for example i have a table for books and i also have another table for genres.

The books table will store all the different books and will have a foreign key of the genre it belongs to using a genre_id key or something.

When i do a query for genres i want it to display how many books are in that genre eg 2 books in the fantasy genre.

for that i would need a records column? but how do i have that auto incrementing/deleting when new records are added or deleted?

EDIT:

Wow thanks for all the help so quickly, so i understand i don't need a seperate table for records but say i wanted it to work with this

```
function all_get() { 
    $this->load->database(); 
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM books;'; 
    $query = $this->db->query($sql); 
    $data = $query->result();
    $this->response($data, 200); 
}
```

how would i do the query to show the records each genre has instead of all the seperate books showing individually?

Comment: Why do you need a records column? You can just SELECT count(*) FROM books WHERE genre = xy.

Comment: Why do you want to keep a column in the table when you can compute the required data by a simple query

Comment: but would that work if i were to do a query for all books and wanted to show how many records there were for all? Im just not sure how that would work or what documentation to read for this.. even if it sounds like basic

Comment: Yes it would. A book about relational database systems might be a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I may have misunderstood, initially I thought these are really two separate questions - one on creating an auto incrementing primary key and another on how to show the number of books in each genre.

### Counts

On showing the number of books in each genre as well as the name of the genre, I think you're looking for something like this:

```
SELECT g.genreName, count(*) from books b
JOIN genres g on g.ID = b.genreID
GROUP BY g.genreName
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3c45e/2

### Auto incrementing

As others have already commented, you don't need a separate records table, but in case you still need help with auto incrementing primary keys, here's the most basic example from [W3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp):

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
 ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 FirstName varchar(255),
 Address varchar(255),
 City varchar(255),
 PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

Comment: His question was'n about an auto_increment key. He wanted to have his *record* column auto incremented to reflect the number of books.

Comment: When you say "show the records each genre has instead of all the separate books showing individually" I assume you are asking how to simply show the number of books in each genre which is what COUNT(*) does (you just have to remember to include the GROUP BY part at the end of your query, otherwise the query will fail).

Comment: if i was searching for all genres what would i put instead of the genre name? Im only testing with apigee console at the moment

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you are asking what input to provide? i.e. given a genre, how many books are in that genre? In which case, I would recommend supplying genreID. So add `WHERE b.genreID = 1 /* Fantasy */`.

Comment: Btw, I added a link to SQL Fiddle, which clarifies my answer.

Comment: ah ive currently got it working with supplying the genre title i could make it work with genre id too i guess which do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a records column. You can query how many books are related to each genre:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM Book WHERE genre_id = :genreId;
```

BTW before you start you might rethink your entity relations. Is Genre <-> Book really 1:n?

Comment: So you don't have books which fit in more genres. That's ok.

Comment: they might fit into other genres but i dont want to overcomplicate it until i can get this basic function working